Feynman rule from dynamical Chern-Simons
Consider the following action that
\begin{equation}
    S = \int d^4x\sqrt{-g}\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^2 + V(\phi) + \frac{2R}{\kappa^2} 
- \frac{\phi}{4f}{}^*RR\right)
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    {}^*RR = {}^*R^\rho{}_\sigma{}^{\mu\nu}R^{\sigma}{}_{\rho\mu\nu}\:\:\text{and}\:\: {}^*R^\rho{}_\sigma{}^{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}R^\rho{}_{\sigma\alpha\beta}.
\end{equation}
Now, if I consider the expansion of the metric as $g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu} + \kappa h_{\mu\nu}$ where $\kappa^2 = 32\pi G$ (or $\kappa^2 = m_{\text{pl}}^{-2}$). Then the linearized version of Riemann and the dual Riemann tensor are given as the following up to $\mathcal{O}(h)$
\begin{align}
    R_{\sigma\tau\alpha\beta} &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_\beta\partial_\tau h_{\sigma\alpha} - \partial_\alpha\partial_\tau h_{\sigma\beta} + \partial_\alpha\partial_\sigma h_{\tau\beta} - \partial_\beta\partial_\sigma h_{\tau\alpha}\right)\\
    {}^*R_{\sigma\tau}{}^{\mu\nu}& = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\partial_\alpha\left(\partial_\sigma h_{\tau\beta} - \partial_\tau h_{\sigma\beta}\right).
\end{align}
Their product is then
\begin{equation}
    {}^*RR = \epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\partial_\alpha\left(\partial_\sigma h_{\tau\beta} - \partial_\tau h_{\sigma\beta}\right)\partial_\nu\partial^\sigma h^\tau_\mu.
\end{equation}
Now, suppose that I want the Feynman rule for $\phi hh$ scattering from the $\phi{}^*RR$ term (and that I have included the proper gauge-fixing term in the form of the Harmonic (or de Donder gauge) $S\supset \int\sqrt{-g}\Gamma^\mu\Gamma_\mu$ where $\Gamma_\mu = \partial^\nu h_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu h$ for finding the graviton propagator). Then after a few integration by parts I am stuck at the following part (where integration by parts is lazily performed as $A\partial_\mu B = -B\partial_\mu A$ assuming proper boundary conditions)
\begin{align}
{}^*RR & =\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\left(\partial_\alpha\partial_\sigma h_{\tau\beta} - \partial_\alpha\partial_\tau h_{\sigma\beta}\right)\partial_\nu\partial^\sigma(h_{\mu\rho}\eta^{\rho\tau})\\
& = \epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\eta^{\rho\tau}\left(h_{\mu\rho}\Box\partial_\alpha\partial_\nu h_{\tau\beta} - h_{\mu\rho}\partial_\alpha\partial_\tau\partial_\nu\partial^\sigma h_{\sigma\beta}\right). 
\end{align}
Now, I can pull one factor of $h_{\mu\rho}$ out but I can not pull out another to put it into the form of
\begin{equation}
{}^*RR = h_{\mu\nu}T^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}h_{\alpha\beta}
\end{equation}
so I can further check to see if it is invertible. Any help or suggestions? I am not sure what I can and can not do with the Levi-Civita tensor $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}$. I am not even sure if I can get a Feynman rule from this but I can not find a reference for this particular term in Feynman rule form since it is graviton-graviton-scalar scattering.
EDIT: A possible start at this problem is to attempt a similar one where we are tring to find the rule for $\phi AA$ scattering from the dynamical U(1) Chern-Simons term $\phi {}^*FF$ where we would want the Feynman rule to be of the form $\phi{}^*FF = \phi A_\mu B^{\mu\nu}A_\nu$.
